# Is there a safe way to use C++11 Smart Pointer and the Interface for Raw Pointer together?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, interface, smart-pointers

I want to use C++11 Smart Pointers in new projects, and encounter a problem. Many current projects still use raw pointers as parameters in their interface and have no interface for smart pointers, e.g. [QMainWindow::setCentralWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

To keep type consistent, I have to pass the stored pointer from `get()` like this segment:

```
QMainWindow win;

std::shared_ptr<QWidget> scrollArea{ std::make_shared<QScrollArea>() };
// QScrollArea is a derived class of QWidget.

win.setCentralWidget(scrollArea.get());
```

But I can't make sure whether other methods in Qt execute operator `delete` on the stored pointer of `scrollArea`.

**Will it cause memory leak or other problems if some methods in Qt do that?**

I've checked the latest [C++ Standard CD](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) and found nothing on that. Seems it's an undefined behavior.

If doing this is an undefined behavior and dangerous, **is there a safe way to use smart pointer(s) with the interface for raw pointer(s)?**

Comment: If you are unsure if Qt executes `delete` how do you ensure there are no memory leaks currently?

Comment: It's the same as if you asked "will deleting a  pointer twice cause some problems?"

Comment: @W.B. My main purpose is to find a solution for this case.

Comment: @hmjd Of course no memory leaks currently. You don't know what `std::shared_ptr` does?

Comment: @UniversE, yes I do. My comment was how you currently know whether to `delete` objects explicitly if you don't know if Qt does it for you?

Comment: @hmjd I use `std::shared_ptr` to avoid using `delete` explicitly. `get()` doesn't release the ownership, and no other `std::shared_ptr` co-owns the object `QScrollArea`. So the memory will be recycled when `scrollArea` destructs. I don't know why I should care whether `delete` the object explicitly out of `win.setCentralWidget(scrollArea.get());`.

Comment: @hmjd Oh, I suddenly know what you mean. You probably mean how to ensure whether there are memory leaks if use **Raw Pointers instead of Smart Pointers** here. That's another case. The problem here is not to evaluate whether exist memory leaks caused by (un `delete` d) raw pointers, but what happens and what to do if smart pointers are executed explicit `delete` before destruct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no such way in the general case. For each "legacy" interface you want to use, you must read its documentation to see how it interacts with ownership (which is what `std` smart pointers encapsulate). A single object can only be managed by one ownership scheme.

With Qt in particular, it's definitely *not* safe to mix smart pointers and Qt management. Qt's parent/child relationship between `QObject`s includes ownership semantics (children are deleted when their parent is), so you cannot safely mix this with any other ownership scheme (such as `std` smart pointers).

Note that the Qt docs you link to explicitly state that "`QMainWindow` takes ownership of the *widget* pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time."

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, if you are using an interface that uses raw pointers, you will need to consult the documentation to determine if the method does or does not take ownership of the provided pointer.

If the function takes ownership, then you must invoke `.release()` to transfer the ownership to the function. If the function does not take ownership, then you would pass the object with `.get()`.

Answer (score 3):

> Will it cause memory leak or other problems if some methods in Qt do that?

It won't introduce a memory leak, since the memory is afterall released. However, since both QT and the `shared_ptr` would call `delete` on that memory, you would likely get some nice heap corruption (UB in general).

> is there a safe way to use smart pointer(s) with the interface for raw pointer(s)?

Sure. Don't have unrelated entities manage the same memory. For that it is adavantegous to use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` when possible. With `unique_ptr` you could call `.release()` to release the memory from the control of the smartpointer, thus giving you the ability to give control over to QT.

Of course you need check the documentation to see when you have to manage memory yourself and when QT will do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be doing any deleting with the QWidget.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it
>   at the appropriate time.

If you have to use smart pointers, you can use a [weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) which won't own or destroy it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an interface which takes raw pointers, you already have the problem that you must know who is responsible for the lifetime of those pointers.

Adding shared_ptr into the mix doesn't change this.

If the interface will possibly delete the object, then you cannot use `std::shared_ptr` safetly. `std::shared_ptr` must control the lifetime of its objects and there's no way around this (without adding another level of indirection)

You can however get some use out of `std::unique_ptr`. If an interface will not delete a pointer, you can safetly pass in `ptr.get()`. If an interface takes ownership of the lifetime of that object, pass in `ptr.release()` and you give up controlling the lifetime yourself.

All in, you can get some usefulness out of smart pointers even with a legacy codebase, but you've got to be a little careful.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't make sure whether other methods in Qt execute operator delete on the stored pointer of scrollArea.

If the widget has a parent, then the QT's memory management will release that object. In that case you must not use a smart pointer, because your application will try to release it twice, and that is an undefined behaviour.